# Get subgraph in Neo4j using top N edges based on edge property

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a graph of `Position` nodes that are connected using direction `:TO` edges. Each node has a `uuid` property and may have many edges from it to other nodes and each edge has a property `probability`. I want to get the subgraph from a particular starting node using only the edges with the top N probabilities *from each node*. For example, if each node has ten edges, I might want to use the three edges with the highest probability.

On top of this I want to exclude all edges that end in an already visited node and, preferably, be able to parameterize the maximum number of levels (`maxLevel` in the apoc procedures, I believe).

The `apoc` path expansion procedures would probably work fine except for the last requirement; there's no apparent way to limit the number of edges, just the number of rows.

I've tried chaining `MATCH` queries together but can't figure out how to limit the number of edges on a per node basis, just the number of rows.

I think I have a few additional ideas that I'm going to work on, but I feel like this has to be a common enough use case that I'm missing something fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MATCH (n:label1)-[e:type]->(m:label2) 
WHERE n.name='xxx' 
WITH n,e1,m 
ORDER BY e1.prop DESC 
LIMIT 3 
MATCH (m)-[e2:type]->(k) 
RETURN n,e1,m,e2,k
```